# MPI - How to partition and communicate my array portions between master and worker processes

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I am having a problem executing my master/worker MPI program.

The goal is to have the master pass portions of the integer array to the workers, have the workers sort their portions, and then return array portion to the master process which then combines the portions into finalArray[].

I think it has something to do with how I'm passing the portions of the array between processes, but I can't seem to think of anything new to try.

My code:

```
int compare(const void * a, const void * b) // used for quick sort method
{
    if (*(int*)a <  *(int*)b) return -1;
    if (*(int*)a >  *(int*)b) return 1;
    return 0;
}

const int arraySize = 10000;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int rank;
    int numProcesses;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProcesses);

    const int PART = floor(arraySize / (numProcesses - 1));

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); //start timer

    //================================= MASTER PROCESS =================================
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        int bigArray[arraySize];
        int finalArray[arraySize];

        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)                                             //random number generator
        {
            bigArray[i] = rand();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numProcesses - 1; i++)
        {
            MPI_Send(&bigArray, PART, MPI_INT, i + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);               // send elements of the array
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numProcesses - 1; i++)
        {
            std::unique_ptr<int[]> tmpArray(new int[PART]);

            MPI_Recv(&tmpArray, PART, MPI_INT, i + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE); //recieve sorted array from workers

            for (int k = 0; k < PART; k++)
            {
                finalArray[PART * i + k] = tmpArray[k];
            }
        }

        for (int m = 0; m < arraySize; m++)
        {
            printf(" Sorted Array:  %d \n", finalArray[m]);                             //print my sorted array
        }
    }

    //================================ WORKER PROCESSES ===============================
    if (rank != 0)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<int[]> tmpArray(new int[PART]);

        MPI_Recv(&tmpArray, PART, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);    //recieve data into local initalized array
        qsort(&tmpArray, PART, sizeof(int), compare);                                   // quick sort
        MPI_Send(&tmpArray, PART, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);                       //send sorted array back to rank 0
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();                               //end timer
    std::cout << "process took: "
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count()    //prints timer
        << " nanoseconds\n ";

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I am fairly new to MPI and C++ so any advice on either subject related to this problem is extremely helpful. I realize there may be many problems with this code so thank you for all help in advance.

Comment: The buffer argument is the array itself, and not its address.

Comment: @Gilles I replaced the argument in the first MPI_Send, but when I try to replace tmpArray, I receive an error: No suitable conversion function from 'std::unique...' to Void*

Comment: sorry, i am not familiar with those C++ goodies. all i can do is suggest using good old `malloc()`, or wait for some else to help.

Comment: Use `&array[0]`. It should work with regular arrays and with most fancy C++ objects as long as the memory is allocated contiguously.